# How to customize the validation error message in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to create a registration page in Django and to check fields validation. I wanna set a custom validation error message to the email field. Can you help me, please?

Here is the view.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, request
from django.db import connection
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
import pyodbc

def newUser(request):  
     form = NewUserFrom(request.POST or None)
     if not form.is_valid():     
          context = {'frmNewUser':form}
          return render(request,'login/newuser.html', context)
     return render(request, "login/welcome.html")
```

Here is the forms.py:

```
from ctypes import alignment
from email import message
from urllib import request
from django import forms

class NewUserFrom(forms.Form):
    error_css_class = 'error'
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput, label="Username")
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, label="Password")
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(label="Confirm password", widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput, label="Name")
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=50, widget=forms.EmailInput, label="Email")

    def clean_password(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        pwd = cleaned_data.get('password')
        cof_pwd = cleaned_data.get('confirm_password')
        # if pwd and cof_pwd:
        if pwd != cof_pwd:      
            raise forms.ValidationError('Password is not match.')
        return cleaned_data
    
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(NewUserFrom,self).clean()
        email = cleaned_data.get('email')
        if email.strip() == "".strip():
            # self.add_error('email','Email is reqiered.')
            raise forms.ValidationError('Email is reqiered.')
        else: 
            fistPart, secPart = str(email).split('@')
            
        raise forms.ValidationError('Email error.')
```

Here is the NewUser.html:

```
{% block content %}
<form method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        {{frmNewUser.as_table}}
        {% for field in frmNewUser.fields %}
            {% if field.errors %}
                {% for error in field.errors %}
                    <p style="color: red;">{{error}}</p>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="Save" value="Save" colspan=2>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You havn't mentioned against what conditions you want to validate the email. Most of the checks for a normal email shall be done by django in-build validators since you are using `forms.EmailField`. But if you want to do further checks, then you can create another clean method specially for the email field. Just an example to get you started.

```
def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        domain = email.split('@')[1] 
        if (domain == 'gmail') or (domain == 'yahoo'):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Please use your official email id.') 
        return email
```